# Регулярные выражения. получить строку между тегами, но не сами теги

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, match, сопоставление-с-образцом

У меня есть строка следующего вида :

```
<si>
<t>Наименование</t>
</si>
```

Я пытаюсь получить строку без тега si, чтобы результат был

```
<t>Наименование:</t>
```

Мой код :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<si>.*?</si>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(sb.toString());
```

Прошу подскажите, как правильно указать начало и конец строки ?

Мои попытки вроде :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[<si>]^.*?[</si>]$");
```

Не приносят результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Хороший знакомый помог решить эту задачу, оставлю вдруг кому пригодится.

<ваш открывающий тег>(.*?)<закрывающий>

Указать индекс в матчере

String temp = m.group(1);
```